# WooCommerce variation don't work on custom page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have taxnomy-product_cat-drinks.php. All info returns, but variation don't work, then I choose size, color or that ever it don't show price, clear button don't work. There could be the problem?

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="product_all_wrapper">
        <div class="main-product-info">
            <a class="product-content-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-images="<?php echo etheme_get_image_list( $size ); ?>">
                <?php if( $hover == 'swap' ) etheme_get_second_image( $size ); ?>
                <?php echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size ); ?>
                <span>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </span>
            </a>
            <div class="button_view_meal">
                <a>Peržiūrėti</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="after_button_push">
            <div class="text-center product-details">
                <!--  TITLE   -->
                <p class="product-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </p>
                <?php
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
                ?>
                <!--  INFO -->
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that issue was form. I was inserting products into form.